# My program in VB6 need to call a external web API which accepts and returns JSON. Anybody knows calling web api from VB6 and using JSON

Tags: json, vb6

The web service accepts and Returns JSON

Please help me for fixing this problem. Anybody who knows VB6, Web Service, API and JSON can help me.

I have a web service call using XML but I don't know how can I replace XML and JSON in VB6 for POST Request.